# How to take one column each from two different dataframes making a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got two dataframes with time series, where dates are used as index. I would like to create a third dataframe with one column from each of the two initial dataframes, still indexed by date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried.  This is a pretty common operation in Pandas.  Start by looking at their docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1['close'], df2['close']],axis=1)
```